# Example of incomplete measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \nu)$ such that $\nu << \mu$ and $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ complete

Tags: measure-theory

I was tempted at first to say that completeness of measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ implies completeness of $(X, \mathcal{M}, \nu)$ if $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, but apparently I was wrong, so I'm looking for a counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ be any complete measure space such that $\mathcal M$ is not the entire power set of $X$. Let $\nu$ be the zero measure on $\mathcal M$.

Comment: So $(X, \mathcal{M}, \nu)$ is incomplete because $\nu(E) = 0$ for every $E$, yet by definition of $\mathcal{M}$ there are some non-measurable subsets of $X$?